# I don't want to include column in row when drag and sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following table that pull out from database within loop.
I would like to drag and drop the following rows.

The `rowspan` of "Sort" button column is dynamic. (It will be the count of rows).
My problem is when I drag the row to sort, I don't want to include "Sort" button column.

[image]

After I drag the first row, "Sort" button column has been moved with the dragged row as the following.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Poor Semantics

The main problem here is that your save button is part of your table. Why? The `table` element is used to represent tabular data, and a button isn't tabular data.

You'd avoid this problem completely if your HTML was more accurately semantic:

```html
<!-- Section A -->
<section>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
    <button>Save</button>
</section>
```

With this, you'd be able to drag rows and not worry about your `button` being included in the drag at all. You'd have a separate `section` element wrapping each of your related section tables, and the `button` is standalone.

Using CSS we can style the button to be where we want it in relation to the table. A first step being to set the table to `display: inline-table` to allow the button to sit beside it.

---

### Demo

```css
section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
}

button {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Section A</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>SG</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BB</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>JP</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Save</button>
</section>

<section>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Section B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>SG</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BB</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>JP</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Save</button>
</section>
```